# Binary classification or unknown class in random forest in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, prediction

Is there a way to either introduce an 'unknown' category in a random forest or to do binary classification?

I would like to feed data into a random forest which I would only like to classify if the percentage of votes is more than 70%. I have 6 categories in total, so what I initially did was create one random forest, and the cut off values automatically default to `c(16.6, 16.6, 16.6, 16.6, 16.6, 16.6)`. This is rather low, so instead, I would like to either:

- Create one random forest for each category (6 in total) which uses binary classification (either it belongs to the category or it doesn't - so its unknown), then feed the unknown data into the next tree and so on.
- Or, I would like to be able to stick to one random forest, but to introduce new cut off values which allow me to specify that the 'winning' class has to have a proportion of votes greater than 70%, and any data which doesn't is labelled 'unknown'.

The second way currently poses a problem as the cut off values need to sum to 1, and the first suggestion is an issue as I cannot seem to work out how to do binary classification in R.

Is there anyway that either of these can be overcome, and an 'unknown' category be introduced? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice you to keep it simple and not create multiple interlinked binary RF models. You can adopt another aggregation rule than 'majority vote'. You can extract the vote distribution from each predicted sample and from here implement e.g. a 70% majority rule

[image]

@"The second way currently poses a problem as the cut off values need to sum to 1" -Technically, cut off values do not need to sum to one. In randomForest, class predictions are divided by the respective class cut-off and the largest number is the majority winner.

```
library(randomForest)
library(plotrix)
set.seed(1234)
data(iris)
#iris is too easy and therefore applying jitter
iris[1:4] = lapply(iris[1:4],jitter,amount=2)
plot(iris,col=iris$Species)
test = sample(150,25) #reserve a test set
rf = randomForest(Species~.,data=iris[-test,])

#predict test, use type=prob to extract vote fractions
preds = predict(rf,iris[test,],type="prob") 

#make 70% rule
class.winner = apply(preds,1,function(aPred) c(which(aPred>=.7),NA)[1]) 

#plot prediction in probability simplex
triax.plot(preds,col.symbols=iris$Species[test],main="col is true class, o is all pred, x is >=70% preds")
triax.points(preds,col.symbols=unlist(class.winner),pch=4)
```